# Laravel render function works, but when i click button it cannot find component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire class and i can see that it's working because it's rendering both the value and the page. But when i click the button, it gives me an error. This is my file app\http\livewire\actions.php

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Actions extends Component
{   
    public $value="hi";

    public function call()
    {
        $this->value = 'bye';
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.actions');
    }
}
```

This is my blade file under views\livewire

```
<button wire:click="call">SUM</button>
{{$value}}
</div>
```

My page is rendering so when i got to 127.0.0.1:8000/action i see the page and the button.
[image]The value, but when i click the button for call. I get this
Unable to find component: [app.http.livewire.actions] on my page. Any idea how to fix?
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide all full pathnames (from your project root directory), do not cut away the basename as you did with the view. You're hiding the namespace and classname of the livewire component. You're hiding the actual error messages in screenshots. You're not explaining why you expected it to work. Sorry for all those NOTs, what I'm trying to say is that it is of benefit for troubleshooting such issues that you have the relevant parts completely in your question and preferable as text (and screenshots only for additional orientation, not every user can see them, nor can they be searched for).

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I'll try editing my question